# jQuery UI Change buttons based on which DIV is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a jquery dialog, with the buttons parameter.

In my dialog, I have a div which is twice the width with overflow hidden. The buttons are: "Cancel" or "Next". If they click cancel, it goes away. If they click next, the twice width div slides over, showing the next stage. This works fine, but I need then, the buttons, and their actions to change, to say "Go Back" which would slide back, and "Submit" which would submit a form. I have this, so far:

```
    the_form.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 700,
    height: 500,
    'open': function(){
        $('#new_membership_form_content').load('/ajax', {'index': the_form.attr('data-index'), 'race_index': the_form.attr('data-index')});
    },
    'close': function(){
        $('#new_membership_form_content').html('<img src="/wait.gif"/>');
    },
    buttons: {
        'Cancel': function(){
            the_form.dialog('close');
        },
        'Next': function(){
            $("#join_form_container").animate({
                left: '-672px',
            }, 1500, "easeOutExpo");
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be fantastic! :D Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is pseudo code for what I'm trying to achieve. It doesn't work, though... (Ignore the contents of the functions, they're just pasted).

```
        buttons: {
        if($("#join_form_container").css("left") == "0px"){
            'No, thanks'     : function(){the_form.dialog('close')},
            'Add to basket'  : function(){$("#join_form_container").animate({left: '-672px'}, 1500, "easeOutExpo")},
        }else{
            'Go back'        : function(){$("#jasdainer").animate({left: '-672px'}, 1500, "easeOutExpo")},
            'Submit'         : function(){$("#jasdainer").animate({left: '-672px'}, 1500, "easeOutExpo")}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery bind() and unbind() methods? You could just bind the click function initially, unbind when they are changed and bind the new click event function to the button.

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Hi, Marc. I've looked at bind and unbind, but I don't have a clue how to implement them into my code. Can you expand on your answer please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I would have some sort of flag representing when you want to change the button functions, or you can call a function to handle the rebinding of the buttons.

When your css changes, call rebindCancel() such as below

```
function rebindCancel() {
    $('#cancelButton').unbind('click');
    $('#cancelButton').bind('click', function(event) {
        //Add the code for what you want the Cancel button to rebind to
});
```

And then you can have another method that does the opposite to rebind it back to its initial state.

Alternatively, You can have a flag.

```
var cssChanged = false;
function rebindCancel() {
    $('#cancelButton').bind('click', function(event) {
        if (cssChanged == false) {
             //Bind the initial code here
        } else {
            //Bind the alternate code here when the css left == 0px
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I don't understand how any of this applies to my code. Did you see my edit of pseudo code suggesting what I'm trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: No problem. So, The basic idea of my example is that you need to have some sort of flag or trigger event that will change the buttons depending on what state they are in. Your pseudo code will not work because the if else statement needs to be triggered as it is not continuously checking if the left css is at 0px. My example was just trying to explain how you could trigger the if else statement.

Comment: Ah! Of course... Thanks for your perseverance. I pointed out only the other day to a colleague how an if/else wouldn't work because it'd only run once at runtime, and instead it needed to be bound to an event to trigger a re-run. I'm having one of those days. Thanks for your help.